# OutOfMemoryException when processing large list in C#

Tags: c#, list, file

I have to process some big tabular data files (ex.: 300.000 rows by 200 columns), creating a data structure for each cell.

However, in a few thousands iterations a System.OutOfMemoryException is thrown (computer has 8GB RAM).

In my case, I parse each line as a List of Dictionary, since I must have the column name and the value, and process it by creating a node with these information.

Here is the code:

```
// foreach record 
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> inst in c.TodasInstancias)
{
instance = null;
tmp = null;

// for each column
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in inst)
{
    if ((tmp = this.Relations.Find(new Predicate<Relacionamento>(x => x.Target.Name == kv.Key))) != null)
   { // if this class has a relationship with other classes
       p = og.CreateUriNode(this.UriOntologiaPrefix + ":" + kv.Key);
       o = og.CreateUriNode(new Uri(tmp.CampoOrigem.Classe.Configs.Name_space + "/" + kv.Value));
       og.Assert(instancia, p, o);
   }
   else (kv.Key != c.Configs.Identificador)
   { // se for um campo comum de dados
       p = og.CreateUriNode(this.UriOntologiaPrefix + ":" + kv.Key);
       o = og.CreateLiteralNode(kv.Value);
       og.Assert(instancia, p, o);
   }
}
}
```

Any hint on how to bypass this exception?

Comment: You are running out of memory, so you can't by pass it. Your computer can't continue because it needs memory to operate. You need to find a more efficient way of processing your data, ie algorithms, data structures, file types, languages, etc.

Comment: Each _line_ is a `LIst<Dictionary>`? Don't create intermediate structures go directly from line to final node.

Comment: Elijah is correct, you only have so much process memory. Look into *streaming* this data from an external source, rather than loading the entire set into memory at once.

Comment: @ElijahTate yes, that is what I meant. Any other suggestions of more efficient form to process the data.

Comment: @NWard do you have examples on how to stream data from a file and not load it at once?

Answer (score 1):

Use queryable to handle big lists.
You can retrieve batch of records, instead of all data you need using Skip and Take.
This way you will handle a small list in memory each time. 
Ex:

```
   var count=context.entities.Count(); 

   for(i=0,i<count,i+=1000)//1000 can be any size of batch
   {
       var batch =context.entities.Skip(i).Take(1000);
       //Do Operations you need
   }
```